# Is it possible to get list of all the applications that user has installed?

Tags: android

Several games and apps show adds like install the app to get rewards. How does that function?  Can I get the list of all the apps that user has installed on his device including uninstalled apps, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get list of installed non-system apps

```
 public void installedApps() {
        List<PackageInfo> packList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < packList.size(); i++) {
            PackageInfo packInfo = packList.get(i);
            if ((packInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
                String appName = packInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
                Log.e("App № " + Integer.toString(i), appName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try it tomorrow. Can you please tell how can I list system apps as well.

Comment: well you can make your custom arraylist and inside this method loop add the app name in your arraylist and you can set adapter after or show it in textview depends on what u need

Comment: i would like to note that if you want all apps even system apps just remove if check line